# QGis - From highway mileage to longitude latitude

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I'm using QGis and would like to convert the progressive mileage of a highway into latitude/longitude coordinates, but I have no idea how to do it.

I have a Csv dataset where there are several "geo-referenced" information with the progressive mileage of the highway. The Dataset takes this aspect:

```
+--------------+---------------------+----------+
| Highway name | Progressive mileage | FeatureS | 
+--------------+---------------------+----------+ 
| A            |               400.1 |      ... | 
| A            |               430.2 |      ... |
| A            |               520.5 |      ... |
| B            |                22.8 |      ... |
| B            |                50.3 |      ... |
+--------------+---------------------+----------+
```

What I am trying to do with QGis (or welcome if there is an easier way) is to translate the progressive kilometers of the highway into latitude and longitude coordinates. This in order to subsequently represent each feature of the dataset on the map.
About the progressive kilometers of the highway, I know that is known the latitude and longitude of the initial mileage (km 400).

My goal is to have the possibility to make geographical queries in which reporting the name of the highway and the progressive mileage, I get the latitude and longitude of the point

How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a vector layer of your highway lines? If so, then you can generate what you want with a PostGIS query, provided a correctly oriented linestring for each highway, a table with your progressive mileages (as shown above), and a last table containing the lat/lon of your origin points, the highway name, and km values at the origin.

Comment: This a common case for Linear Referencing and Dynamic Segmentation. Do you know if you have a calibrated route?

Comment: What I was able to do is:
1) Extract the highway network of interest from OSM 2) Through the function shortest route from point to point, I divided the highway into vectors 3) What I got is one vector for each highway.    -- Considering that for each vector, therefore for each highway, I know the correspondence: _Progressive & Initial Coordinates_ and _Progressive & Final Coordinates_ is enough to query the highway vectors with queries in which I step as parameters: _HighwayName & MileageProgression_ to get the Coordinates of the point? @FSimardGIS

Comment: What I have is a vector for each highway, generated with the shortest route function from point to point. It's enough? @FranciscoPuga

Comment: So you have a line for each highway spanning from the initial mileage to the final mileage?

Comment: exactly! @FSimardGIS

Comment: That is not a calibrated route, @FSimardGIS approach seems good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution in PostGIS, assuming the following data structure:

- A table **HighwayEvents** containing fields *Highway_name*, *Progressive_km*, *Features* (= your imported csv dataset)
- A table **HighwayOrigins** containing fields *Highway_name*, *Start_km*, *End_km*
- A table **Highways** containing your prepared highway lines with fields *Highway_name* and *geom* for the geometry.

Before running the query, make sure you have only 1 linestring per highway, chopped at the start and end km, and that the lines are correctly oriented, meaning the lines' direction are the same as your increasing mileages. Also check that your events all fall between your start and end km, otherwise you'll have to filter those out.

Here is the PostGIS query that will generate your event point layer:

```
SELECT h."Highway_name", 
       he."Features", 
       he."Progressive_km",
       ST_LineInterpolatePoint(h.geom, (he."Progressive_km" - ho."Start_km") / (ho."End_km" - ho."Start_km")) as pointgeom
FROM your_schema."Highways" as h
INNER JOIN your_schema."HighwayEvents" as he ON h."Highway_name" = he."Highway_name"
INNER JOIN your_schema."HighwayOrigins" ho ON h."Highway_name" = ho."Highway_name"
```

Simply change the schema, table and field names to match yours if needed.

Adding this as a QueryLayer from the DB Manager in QGIS, with a test dataset, here is the result:

[image]